# Play framework! How to limit the requests only from one host

Tags: java, playframework

I am using Play! 1.2.5 and I am not sure the approach I have designed is the best way or not!

I want to limit the requests that application accepts to only those which are received from the **proxy** machine.

I could not find such a feature in the `application.conf` so I wrote a plugin to check the IP address before invoking each action:

```
public class MyPlugin extends PlayPlugin {

  @Override
  public void beforeActionInvocation(Method method) {
    System.out.println("\naction: " + method.getName());
    String ip = Http.Request.current.get().remoteAddress;
    ip = ip.trim();    
    System.out.println("\nIP: " + ip);

    if (!ip.equals("x.x.x.x")) {
      // i don't know how to stop invocation of ActionMethod 
    }
  }
}
```

Now, if it is the right way, how can I stop invocation of action method when the IP address is not the proxy machine IP address?

Comment: I prefer to leave it to the front-end http server, .e.g nginx rather than implementing it as a part of the java application

Comment: How can I do it on Play! built in Netty?

Comment: your implementation is the way to get it done on Play. To stop the action method, just write `throw new play.mvc.results.NotFound("")`

Comment: Green, can you post your solution as an answer instead of a comment so it can be accepted and clearer for future references.